# Kubernetes Public IP failed after service redeploy

Tags: kubernetes

I am running Kubernetes on GCE to deploy 3 microservices, each one with a different public IP. I did not succeed to use "ingress", so I turned my attention to services published as "LoadBalancer"s. This worked for a while but after a redeploy I was no longer able to get a new public IP.

Here is what worked for me once:

```
kubectl create -f helianto-mailer-deployment.yaml
kubectl expose deployment helianto-mailer --type='LoadBalancer' --port=80 --target-port=8082
```

**Question**: Is there any other action required? Do I need to clean a firewall rule or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: it was a quota limit. Kubernetes free trial limits the public static ips you can have. Upgrading the plan was enough to have it working.